# Customize subject of EmailService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, email, mandrill

I'm trying to customize email subject, my idea its users write their own subject... so, when I received mail in subject space, appears user input.. but I only gets No Subject
What I'm doing wrong?

```
 public void Contact(String Name, String Email, String Subject, String Description)
    {
        Subject.Replace("{Subject}", Subject);

        var templateText = GetTemplateHtml("Contacto.html");


        templateText = templateText
            .Replace("{Comentario}", Description)
            .Replace("{Email}", Email)
            .Replace("{Name}", Name);

        EmailBody = templateText;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if Subject = "{Subject}"

Have you put a breakpoint in the code, to confirm that value? 
Are you passing this value in your code?
Also, you aren't actually doing anything further with this value.

Comment: I put a breakpoint, values I insert into my subject field pass for Subject parameter, but mail service dont read it as subject...

Comment: The problem is that you are missing a lot of code. If I follow your code snippet you have a class with some properties, maybe should paste the rest of the code?